# How can I transfer details in a texture to details in a mesh for 3D printing?

Tags: texturing, materials

I have this model:

[image]

The mesh itself is just a simple arc with no details. I want to transfer the lines that appear in the texture into the mesh as actual etched details.  Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *Displace* modifier:

- Unwrap your object correctly
- Subdivide it enough
- Give it a *Displace* modifier, click on *New* then on the *Show Texture* button, it will open the *Texture* panel, here keep *Type > Image or Movie*, click on *Open* and select your texture
- Back into the *Modifier* panel, choose *Coordinates > UV*
- Give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to round it a bit more:

[image]

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, because that just wildly distorts the mesh, no matter how I adjust the settings.

Comment: could you please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file?